# angular spring boot request with image error

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, web, x-www-form-urlencoded

So I am trying to send from Angular to my spring boot backend a image along with some text in a x-wwww-form-urlencoded way.
Here is the angular service method:

```
img(tags:HTMLInputElement, des:HTMLInputElement, selectFile){
    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/add_item"

    const body = new HttpParams()
    body.set("img", selectFile)
    body.set("tags", tags.value)
    body.set("des", des.value)

    return this.http.post<Isecurity[]>(url, body.toString(),{
      headers:new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    } )
  }
```

and on the rest side:

```
@PostMapping("add_item")
    @CrossOrigin
    public  Map<String, Boolean> add_item(@RequestParam MultipartFile img, @RequestParam String tags, @RequestParam String des){
        Map<String, Boolean> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("response", true);
        return values;}
```

I think it is, because of the @RequestParam tags, because the only response, which I get is 500 server error...

Comment: can you provide more detail about the 500 error? (provide the exception that leads to the 500 http error status

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing params in the wrong way. You just kept the name of params as body, but it is not actually the body.

You need to pass params using **'?'** after the url.

So you have to update your code in .ts file as the below lines:

```
img(tags:HTMLInputElement, des:HTMLInputElement, selectFile){
let url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/add_item?"

const params= new HttpParams()
params.set("img", selectFile)
params.set("tags", tags.value)
params.set("des", des.value)

return this.http.post<Isecurity[]>(url+params.toString(),{
  headers:new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
} )
```

}